# How to change fixed columns color and display POSIXct data in DT::datatable Shiny?

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I am using the `superhero` theme in Shiny together with the line below that helps to make the filter's text color black,

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
    tags$head(tags$style("div.dataTables_scrollHead span {color: black;}")),
    ...
)
```

**1.** However, the fixed columns (time column 1) color is not inconsistent with that of the theme. It is white and difficult to see text. How do I change that to match the color of the superhero theme or change it to a more user friendly color?

**Update:** So I managed to the change fixed column color but I want one row to be dark blue and another to be light blue. Plus the row  index and column header are still in white, as shown in image below.

```
output$mytable     <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(df,rownames = T,
                                                     filter="top", 
                                                      extensions = "FixedColumns",style = 'bootstrap',
                                                      options = list(scrollX = TRUE, scrollY = TRUE,
                                                                     autoWidth = F,
                                                                     columnDefs = list(list(width = '145px', targets = c(1))),
                                                                     fixedColumns=list(leftColumns=2))) 
                                                     %>%formatRound(c(2:l_agg), 2)%>% formatStyle('Timestamp',backgroundColor='#2B3E50'))
```

[image]

**Updated Image**
[image: Updated Image]

**2.** And right now the fixed column (time) is of `character` type (casted from `POSIXct` to character), I tried to put `POSIXct` time in the `datatable` but the time zone is different. How should I have the time column with type `POSIXct` and format it properly in datatable ?

For instance this is the time series data I have, and ideally I want Shiny the data shown as below without the CST part.

```
[1] "2020-04-06 09:31:20.000 CST" "2020-04-06 09:31:51.000 CST" "2020-04-06 09:32:21.000 CST" "2020-04-06 09:32:50.000 CST"
[5] "2020-04-06 09:33:21.000 CST" "2020-04-06 09:33:51.000 CST"
```

The structure is

```
structure(c(1586136680.0005, 1586136711.0005, 1586136741.0005, 
1586136770.0005, 1586136801.0005, 1586136831.0005), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

However, in Shiny, it is displayed as below, which is not what I want.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it really need to be of class `Posixct` to be displayed in a table? Why not just convert it to CST time zone then convert the dates to character?

On your second question about your row numbers being white, we can use custom `css` tags to define row colours and include the CSS in `tags$head(tags$style(HTML())))`. We can add the CSS you used in this same call as well. Note that the CSS defined here affects the row number colours. The column with data rows have their colour defined by `backgroundColor = styleEqual(df$Timestamp, row_colours)`. We use CSS to match the colour of the row number to the colour of the rest of the row.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(timeDate)

df <- structure(c(1586136680.0005, 1586136711.0005, 1586136741.0005,1586136861.0005, 1586136861.0005,
                  1586136801.0005, 1586136831.0005, 1586136861.0005), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                "POSIXt"), tzone = "") 

df <- data.frame(Timestamp = df)

df$Timestamp <- as.character(.POSIXct(df$Timestamp-3600*7, tz="CST6CDT"))

l_agg <- 10

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('

  table th {
    background:#4e5d6c;
}

  table tr:nth-child(odd) td{
           background:#2B3E50;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td{
            background:#4e5d6c;
}

div.dataTables_scrollHead span {color: black;}

'))),

  theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")

) 

if (!round(length(df$Timestamp)/2,0) %% 2) {
  row_colours <- rep(c('#2B3E50', '#4e5d6c'), length(df$Timestamp)/2)
  } else {
  row_colours <- rep(c('#2B3E50', '#4e5d6c'), round(length(df$Timestamp)/2,0))[-length(df$Timestamp)]
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mytable     <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(df,rownames = T,
                                                          filter="top", 
                                                          extensions = "FixedColumns",style = 'bootstrap',
                                                          options = list(scrollX = TRUE, scrollY = TRUE,
                                                                         autoWidth = F,
                                                                         columnDefs = list(list(width = '1444px', targets = c(1))),
                                                                         fixedColumns=list(eftColumns=1))) 
                                            %>%formatRound(c(2:l_agg), 2)%>% formatStyle('Timestamp',backgroundColor = styleEqual(df$Timestamp, row_colours)))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding the timestamp part, it’s already in character class now. I am thinking of taking this out of this question.

Comment: I m trying out the code. Just want to ask what is `df_lev` and why is `nrow(df)/2`, my code generated an error msg saying `length(levels) must be equal to length(values)`

Comment: Seems like adding the CSS code is enough to make the fixed column (timestamp) looks like the rest of the other columns. Adding the `formatStyle` for `timestamp` just make the entire column have the darkblue color. Thanks a lot. I know nothing about `CSS` but is there a way to merge the 2 `tags$head(tags$style` statement ? Or they have to be 2 separate statements because one is assigning color table backgrounds and rows and other is assigning color to column header ?

Comment: No, you can add them in the same tag. I've edited my answer once more to reflect this. Hope this solves eveything

Comment: Great thanks a lot for the superb answer. Exactly what I am looking for. One last thing: the CSS code and `formatStyle(...row_colours)` do the same thing, correct ? And `row_colours` may not work as expected if the row number is an odd number.

Comment: Happy to help. Glad the code does what you wanted. I've added a final edit that handles the case when df has odd number of rows by rounding the length argument and then removing the last row if df is odd. The css makes the color of the row number background match the background of the rest of the row. the color of the part of the row where the data is supplied by ````formatStyle(...row_colours)````. You can verify this to be the case by playing around with the colours of both.